# Disqus Dynamic Variables in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, disqus

Working through a RoR blog website tutorial, but I got stuck at adding Disqus. It doesn't like how I'm writing my dynamic variables. Still pretty new to all of this.

```
<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
<script>

var disqus_config = function () {
this.page.url = '<%= url_for([@post, {only_path: false}]) %>';
this.page.identifier = '<%= @post.id %>';
this.page.title = '<%= @post.title %>';
};

(function() { // DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
var d = document, s = d.createElement('script');
s.src = 'https://myshortname.disqus.com/embed.js';
s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
(d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
})();
</script>
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="https://disqus.com/?ref_noscript">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
```

**Update**
I noticed that my url is not displaying properly. Inspecting the disqus javascript revealed:

```
var disqus_config = function () {
this.page.url = '/posts/5'; //This should be a complete url
this.page.identifier = '5';
this.page.title = 'Article 5';
};
```

Comment: is it a `xyz.html.erb` file?

Comment: Can you elaborate on error messages, console logs, and/or the event that should occur compared to the events that did occur?

Comment: Sure thing, it's in a _disqus.html.erb file. I'm not getting any errors, I'm just receiving the message: "we were unable to load disqus." It seems to work fine when I comment out the function above.

Comment: Can you show us your full file?

Comment: I added the entire file to my post.

Comment: I see you have solved the problem. You could post that as an answer and accept it. Self-solved questions could turn out to be useful for some other user in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.page.url = '<%= url_for(only_path: false) %>';
```